# How to create a counter by comparing between random number and vector that contains probabilities in R?

Tags: r

I'm a beginner in R :)

I created the following dateframe (just an example, the real data frame contains +2000 rows):

```
RowNum <-c(1:5)
Prob <- c(0.5,0.3,0.8,0.2,0.9)
Attempts <- c(rep(0,5))
Succeeded <- c(rep(0,5))
Overall <- data.frame(RowNum,Prob,Attempts,Succeeded)
```

I want to create the following:

Creating random number (between 0-1) ->
A. If the random number is lower than the prob in the first row -> add 1 to Attempts and 1 to Succeeded (just for the first row) and then create another random number and move to the next row and check if is greater or lower - if is lower, add 1 to Attempts and 1 to Succeeded (just for the second row) and then create another random number and move to the next row...and so on...
B. If the random number is greater than the prob in the first row -> add 1 only to Attempts (just for the first row) and then create another random number and do the same but don't continue to the next row.

It's like creating a counter for each element in the vector, and to calculation should move to the next row only when the random number is lower than the prob.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Assume that the 5 random numbers are `c(0.6469028, 0.3942258, 0.6185018, 0.4768911, 0.1360972) `(generated from this `set.seed(2020); runif(5)`). Given these random numbers, can you edit your question and show us the expected output using your example dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made two functions to solve this. `addone` is a recursive function that will call itself again if the random is greater than `Prob`. `make.new.df` is just a for loop to cycle through the rows.

Confused about the `succeeded` column, only one success before moving on to the next row, so `succeeded` will only ever be 1?

```
set.seed(1)

addone <- function(vec) {
    vec$Attempts <- vec$Attempts + 1
    if(runif(1) < vec$Prob) {
        vec$Succeeded <- vec$Succeeded + 1
    } else {
        vec <- addone(vec)
    }
    vec
}


make.new.df <- function(df) {
    for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
        df[i, ] <- addone(df[i, ])
    }
    df
}

df1 <- make.new.df(Overall)
df1
```

Here is the output using `set.seed(1)`

```
  RowNum Prob Attempts Succeeded
1      1  0.5        1         1
2      2  0.3        4         1
3      3  0.8        3         1
4      4  0.2        2         1
5      5  0.9        1         1
```

Comment: Would be fun to see a `dplyr` or `apply` solution to this with no `for` loops.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Regarding succeeded - you are right, I want to create a for loop that will simulate several iterations. To do so I just need to insert for loop in the beginning of the code? And another question, I ran the code that you wrote and I don't see any results, how can I see the results of the new df that you created?

Comment: Call the function with `df1 <- make.new.df(Overall)`, then view the results with `df1`. I added those steps to the code above.